# Ruby on Rails: Can't access User Attributes From a Comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In this application, I have a Recipe model, User model(Devise), and a Comment model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
  has_many :comments
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

This is what my Comments Controller looks like.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
    @comment = @recipe.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to root_path #change this the the appropriate path later
    end
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

This is the error that I am getting

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass):
68:     <p><%= @recipe.comments.count %> Comments</p>
69:     <% @recipe.comments.each do |comment| %>
70:       <p><%= comment.content %><p>
71:       <%= comment.user.first_name %>
72:     <% end %>
73:   </div>
74: </div>
```

So the problem occurs when I try accessing the first_name attribute. If I do just 'comment.user' it spits out # User:0x007f8f4f9b6780.

I looked in the Rails Console and saw that my comments are saving. In the Rails Console, I am able to do

```
@recipe = Recipe.first
@recipe.comments.first.user.first_name => "John"
```

This is the actual code that's failing

```
<% @recipe.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% byebug %>
  <p><%= comment.content %><p>
  <p><%= comment.user.first_name %></p>
<% end %>
```

I tried using byebug to debug, and I'm able to do 'comment.user.first_name' => John

I'm not sure what I have wrong here and would appreciate the help. Rails 4.2.0 btw

Edit: RecipeController#Show

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
  before_action :find_recipe, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]


  ...

  def show

  end

  private

  def find_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def find_recipe
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment Form Partial

```
<div class="container">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= form_for([@recipe.user, @recipe, @recipe.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're iterating over the collection of Comments

```
@recipe.comments.each
```

The error you've mentioned occurs, because ONE of comments doesn't have `user` set (which causes `first_name` call on `nil`, and the error you've mentioned).

Try modifying your template as follows, to track the "problematic" comment:

```
<% @recipe.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p><%= comment.content %><p>
  <% if comment.user.nil? %>
    Anonymous
  <% else %>
    <%= comment.user.first_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!

**Update**

Try updating `RecipesController`:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
end
```

And replace `@recipe.comments.build` in partial:

```
<div class="container">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= form_for([@recipe.user, @recipe, @comment]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :content %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :content %><br>
      <br>
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

You don't need "linking" `@recipe` and `Comment` at that point, as it will be properly handled in `CommentsController#create`.

That was nice exercise!

Comment: Great Idea! I didn't think to do that. What I am seeing now is, my comment counter '@recipe.comments.count' says '1 comment'. It shows the comment, and the user's first_name, which is good. But then there's an Anonymous beneath is. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Yup - try in your template (just for debugging) `<%= comment.id %>`, and later in console, check, if `Comment` of that ID has `User` set! `c = Comment.find(id)` `p comment.user`. This should prove, that the comment does not have a user.

Comment: You might try setting the user in console with `c.user = User.first` `c.save` and refresh your page

Comment: And one more thing - I assumed that the code of your you've provided is just an excerpt so we can focus on the minimal amount of code, but you should consider the case that @Chambeur mentioned in his answer

Comment: this is probably very bad practice, but since this is a personal practice project i decided to drop my databases and start from scratch. when i did that, i created a new user, created a new recipe. On the recipe page, it shows "anonymous" already before I added any comments. in the console, it doesn't look like there are any comments.

Comment: Could you add the code of your `RecipiesController#show`? (I'm assuming this is the action for template you're trying to render)

Comment: That's weird, that you get anonymous. If you paste the same code Pawel gave you, then it means that there is a comment in your recipe. Maybe you are creating a comment at the same moment when you create the recipe. Can you add the code of your `RecipiesController#create` too ?

Comment: Hmm... This is strange. Based on code you've provided, that the "anonymous" is displayed on your page, since it should be part of a loop, and in case, there are no `Comment`s for `Recipe`, the loop should not be executed... Maybe there is any other occurrence of "anonymous" string in your template?

Comment: It's weird because that anonymous is coming from `comment.user.nil?`, but my `@recipe.comments.count` shows 0. There is also no `comment.id` associated with the Anonymous.

Comment: Ok, we need more debugging... Could you put `<%= comment.inspect %>` inside your loop? What is displayed on your page when refreshed?

Comment: This shows up when I add that line of code: `#<Comment id: nil, content: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, recipe_id: 1>`

Comment: So yes - this is definitive answer. Your `@recipe` has one, empty `Comment`, which has no `User` associated, thus the "anonymous" is rendered... Now we need to find, where is that empty comment coming from... Could you add the code of whole template of `show`?

Comment: I cut out some code on my `show` template and it looks like the comment form partial is what is adding that single empty `Comment`.

Comment: @recipe.comments.build ;) Nice debugging Pawel.

Comment: Yup, I've been suspecting this, but I wanted to have clear evidence of if! ;) If `@recipe.comments.count` was showing 0, so the comment was build somewhere later (unfortunately, maybe in any of templates/partials).

Comment: @Chambeur - Updated answer! Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! This is great. Thanks for persisting and following through with me!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you never check if the `current_user` exists.
So when you iterate in each comments, if a someone, who's not log in, posts a comment, the user will be nil.

To prevents this error, you can add this Devise Helper in your controller :

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_pro_user!
```

It will automaticaly redirect to the sign in view if someone try to access the comments controller.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to handle that is using delegation and allowing nil, let me explain

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recipe

  delegate :first_name, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

This will create a method called `user_first_name` (`user` is the `prefix`), and `allow_nil` means if user doesn't exist return `nil`

The view code will be like this

```
<% @recipe.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p><%= comment.content %><p>
  <p><%= comment.user_first_name %></p> # notice it's 1 dot
<% end %>
```

When the loop reaches a comment that doesn't have a user, it will return `nil` which will turn into an empty string,
While when the user exists, the comment will go ask the user to return it's `first_name`